# How to show tooltip only for text-overflow:ellipsis in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I need to display the tooltip only when the ellipsis occurs for a text using angular js without using bootstrap.Please help me on this.

**HTML**

```
    <div class="list tooltipSection tooltip" title="{{orderList.CustName}}" ng-if="UserType === 'Employee'">{{orderList.CustName}}</div>
```

Comment: What have you tried? Please share the code.

Comment: This is my HTML code    <div class="list tooltipSection tooltip" title="{{orderList.CustName}}" ng-if="UserType === 'Employee'">{{orderList.CustName}}</div>.Am new to angular js am not getting how to check ellipsis for the text.